# Find and Replace Multiple fields?

Tags: excel, email, replace, find

I am struggling to find a solution for my issue.

I have two excel documents, one with fields of "existing email addresses" and the other with "new clients email address"

I don't want to send an e-mail to the "existing email addresses" so i need to search the "new client email addresses" for any "existing email addresses" and remove them,

Unfortunately I don't want to do a find and replace for hundreds of fields.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks Josh

Comment: use `=(MATCH()>0)` to find if the email_address exists in the new list. Then filter on all False rows and delete or use `INDEX & MATCH` or `VLOOKUP` to update your column

Comment: Thank you Tom, this solved the issue =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$5,0)),"",A1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completed this with a duplicate field thanks to Tom.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$5,0)),"",A1)
```